# A surjective graph homomorphism between 4-valent graphs

Tags: graph-theory

Let $K$ and $L$ be $4$-valent planar graphs with Euler circuits (where the choice of the next edge in the circuit consists of the edge which does not share a face with the edge before), with $|V(K)| = n \cdot |V(L)|$ where $|V(K)|$ denotes the number of vertices in $K$.

Let $f: K \rightarrow L $ be a surjective graph homomorphism mapping the Euler circuit of $K$ to the Euler circuit of $L$ repeated $n$ times. Suppose there exists a face $\lambda$ of $L$ which is bound by $l$ vertices such that there exists a face $\kappa$ in $K$ which is bound by $b \times l$ vertices, which has its vertices mapped surjectively onto the vertices of $\lambda$.

Suppose that $b$ does not divide $n$. Then is it the case that there will exist four vertices $k_{1} , k_{2} , k_{3} , k_{4} $ of $K$ that are part of one face of $K$, and also part of another face?